# What do the symbols mean in this statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having problems breaking this down in order for it to make sense in my head.  How would you read this?  $f(S)=\{f(x)\,|\,x \text{ exists in }S\}$

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: From my textbook. S represents a set.

Comment: Ok now we are getting somewhere with the edit.

Comment: x is a subset of S?

Comment: I think you need one more edit: $f(\mathcal{S}) = \{f(x)|x\mbox{ exists in }\mathcal{S}\}$. Would you double-check?

Comment: Are you sure its not meant to read, "$x$ is an element of $S$"? Btw, you can put dollar signs around math to make it look mathy. Within the dollar signs, write \{ \} for open and close braces, and \in for the membership symbol.

Comment: What does "x exists in $S$" mean? Is that really what the book says? By the way: What textbook is this? "My textbook" is not really helpful.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo It sounds more romantic than $x\in\mathcal{S}$.

Answer (score 4):

Given a set $S$ and a function $f$, it is customary to define
$$
f(S) = \{f(x) \mid x \in S\}.
$$
With this definition, $f(S)$ is the image of $S$ under $f$. In other words, you can obtain $f(S)$ by plugging each element of $S$ into $f$ and collecting the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion that $f(S)=\{f(x) \mid x \in S\}$ amounts to the following.

1. Whenever you see the expression $x=f(s),$ if you furthermore know
   that $s \in S$, then you may deduce that $x \in f(S)$.
2. Whenever you see the expression $x \in f(S)$, you may deduce that
   there exists $s \in S$ such that $x = f(s)$.